# How can I see the results of a shareholder vote (US)?

Tags: sec, shareholder-meeting, edgar

After reading [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/86744/proxy-voting-how-to-learn-more-about-a-proposal/86755#86755) about shareholder proposals, I tried to find the results of the vote.
For the sake of argument, let's say I'm interested in the proposal mentioned in that question, which I believe is described in [this DEF 14A form](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/105544/000093247117004596/0000932471-17-004596-index.htm) and in more details in [the preliminary filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/105544/000093247117004594/0000932471-17-004594-index.htm). How would I go about finding out the outcome of the vote at the shareholder meeting (result and breakdown of votes)?

I imagine the information has to be filed with the SEC, but I've not been able to find the correct form on EDGAR. Are there any other sources of information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most public corporations publish the results of proxy votes in multiple formats included hard-copy and online.  Look for annual/quarterly reports.  The best way to find this is to search their web site for "Investor Relations" and it is likely in a downloadable PDF file.

For example: Here is the page for [Exxon Mobil](https://corporate.exxonmobil.com/Investors/Investor-relations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess this means there is no specific form to be filed with the SEC, but the next annual report should hold the information.