# Is proxy voting advice available for small investors?

Tags: stocks, investing, shareholder-meeting

There are [proxy advisor companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_firm) available for institutional investors, but it doesn't seem like there's any proxy voting advice available for small, individual investors.  Where should a small investor look for a deeper perspective on our proxy vote options?  Does any of the advice from the large firms leak out somewhere?  Does anyone cater to this end of the market or are we too small for anyone to try?

I don't need it to be free advice, but if that is available I'd be happy to start with something more than the scant information I get from the companies I have stocks in.

Meta: [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/86744/35705) is similar to mine, but I'm asking about information from secondary/independent sources and that question is about getting more details from primary sources.

Comment: If you are a small investor, then your vote will make no difference.  You can vote for fun if you like.  But don't think you will change anything.

Comment: I definitely understand that my impact will be small, but I'd like it to be a well-informed small impact.